# Diplaying data clearly on OLED screen

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm using Adrunio with OLED screen to display data obtained from a Taos. This works fine. However, when it comes to producing a graph using the data it gets a bit tricky. The data I want to display is something like 
40.7025442 
39.7726818
39.1689705
38.745451
38.4166179

I have made a code so that these data are referenced to fit into the grid on the screen, however since the data is in very small values, I almost obtain a straight line on the screen. Can anyone help me to display this type of data with no limit to the number of data obtained, so that the trend on the screen can be clearly seen.

Thank you